# Downsides of using Java var keyword

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

A presenter just cited that changing to `var` is useful syntactic-sugar (aligning variable names). I thought I'd check and found...

```java
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); // IMO this is safer future-proof coding
    list.add("HELLO WORLD");
```

... generates bytecode with an [`invokeinterface`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504633/what-is-the-point-of-invokeinterface) dispatch ...

```
 11: invokeinterface #12,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

Converting to Java 10+ `var` ...

```java
    var list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("HELLO WORLD");
```

... generates bytecode with an `invokevirtual` dispatch ...

```
 11: invokevirtual #12                 // Method java/util/ArrayList.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

Should I be concerned with, say, bulk upgrading a whole application's sourcecode with `var`? E.g. Will sensitive sections be slower (or faster?! given `invokeinterface` involves more steps?) Aside from that, are there other non-technical impacts (I saw an interesting comment about the clarity of offline code review for example)

Comment: The reason for that difference is that the assumed type of your `var` is `ArrayList` rather than `List`. As long as you don't *need* your variable type to be `List` in this case, there's no reason it should cause any problem. If you *do* need your variable to be of type `List`, then it's not a suitable case for `var`.

Comment: I don't like `var`, but I'm probably an old grouch.  1. In the case of `List` vs. `ArrayList`, you are not declaring the same type, and are no longer coding to an interface.  2. For simple code, `var` saves little.  For complicated code, `var` makes each maintenance programmer manually verify the type instead of just having it spelled out in black and white. 3. Since `var` doesn't actually declare the type, I feel this makes literate programming harder. (There's probably other reasons, but those are off the top of my head.)

Comment: ... but then I don't see that much is to be gained by changing already written code to use `var` instead of declaring variable types: all those keystrokes used typing in all the variable types have already been performed.

Comment: Mmm, but bulk transform to Java 7 diamond syntax was welcomed by all. There can be merit in freshening old code.

Comment: Diamond Operator didn't really change the semantics of the code; `var` did, a little bit, if you're concerned about programming against interfaces; however, you shouldn't use `var` in polymorphic code. "Manifest type declarations for locals are often perceived to be unnecessary" - is the main motivation of [JEP 286](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286).

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are concerned about? The code is still invoking the same method. The change with a real impact is not even visible there, as you now have  `List<Object>`. You have to use `var list = new ArrayList<String>();`, to parameterize the list with `String`, however, for your simple test code, not even that matters.

Comment: I added some elaboration but I'm asking abut my unknown unknowns! When someone tells me this is a no-op free upgrade, I tend to want details.

Comment: Differences between `invokevirtual` and `invokeinterface` are elaborated in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51112973/2711488). In short, there is no practical difference to the execution.

Comment: I need to understand the issue with var in java, maybe it is new for java developers. However, it has been used in JS for ages and no one complains about code readability there. So is it really a problem with the feature or with the people?

Answer (score 9):

The reason the bytecode differs is because the `var` declaration infers the type `ArrayList` rather than `List`. It's equivalent to you writing `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` explicitly. So if you wouldn't worry about changing `List` to `ArrayList` in your variable declaration, you shouldn't worry about changing it to `var` either.

Answer (score 0):

This is java, not PHP :) So, I wouldn't worry if I were you. The only thing that could happen is that it will not compile and you need to 'revert' the var to typed variable.

The only issue var creates is a headache during code review.

IMHO, at least.